# Emulator - Run Android Tinder app on Windows

Tags: windows, android, emulator

I'm tired of having to use my phone to browse Tinder.

Are there any recommendations for emulators that allow someone to run the Android app on Windows?

I don't want to dual boot my machine.

Comment: That rather sounds like asking for an howto, which would be off-topic here. Shall we interprete it rather as asking for an emulator? You could check the end of [this page](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/emulators) for some candidates.

Comment: @Izzy yes an emulator sounds right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the application in an Androd emulator such as those available in the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) (See [here](http://www.bluestacks.com/apps/lifestyle/tinder-on-pc.html)) or under [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) but this may require quite a lot of disc space.

Alternatively you could use [6tin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/6tin/9wzdncrfhvx1) or [Timber](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/timber/9wzdncrdck1w) which are Windows tinder apps which also run on a PC running Windows 10.

Comment: It doesn't appear Timber is officially supported by Tinder.  Not to mention I get 'This app does not work on your device.'